# R:: fill based on symbols like strokes, lines and dots instead of colours in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

Im interested to know if one can plot a map or any graph by using lines, strokes, points and other symbols instead of colors in ggplot ?

For example instead of such a map :

```
 if (requireNamespace("sf", quietly = TRUE)) {
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA))
```

which would result in a plot like this:
[image: Result of a map (which i dont want like)]

Instead of such a map, is it possible to fill with symbols like

[image: Fill based on this]

Answer (score 1):

You can even use `ggpattern` directly with `sf` objects through `geom_sf_pattern` like this:

```
devtools::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

# here is where the magic happens
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf_pattern(aes(pattern=substr(NAME, 1,1)))
```

[image]

Find a detailed description of the ggpattern package [here](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2020/04/01/introducing-ggpattern-pattern-fills-for-ggplot/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [ggpattern](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggpattern).

Specifically the code in [this example](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/articles/geom-gallery-array.html#geom-map-pattern-):

```
library(maps)

crimes <- data.frame(state = tolower(rownames(USArrests)), USArrests)
crimesm <- reshape2::melt(crimes, id = 1)

states_map <- map_data("state")

p <- ggplot(crimes, aes(map_id = state)) +
    geom_map_pattern(
      map = states_map,
      aes(
        pattern_type = state
      ),
      pattern              = 'magick',
      pattern_fill         = 'black',
      pattern_aspect_ratio = 1.75,
      fill                 = 'white',
      colour               = 'black',
    ) +
    expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat) +
    coord_map() +
    theme_bw(18) +
    labs(title = "ggpattern::geom_map_pattern()") +
  labs(
    title = "ggpattern::geom_map_pattern()",
    subtitle = "pattern = 'magick'"
  ) +
    scale_pattern_type_discrete(choices = ggpattern::magick_pattern_names) +
    theme(legend.position = 'none')

p
```