# geom_sf in black and white?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, geom-sf

I'm trying to produce a figure in black and white with geom_sf. I have seven categories so I want to make some of them patterned (rather than just shades of grey). But I can't seem to get geom_sf into black and white mode even to begin with. Any advice? Below is the code (category denotes which of the seven categories each geographic unit belongs to).

```
fig <- ggplot(data = d)+
  geom_sf(aes(fill = category))+
    theme_bw()
```

Comment: For grayscale fill try `scale_fill_grey()`, though I'm afraid it will not help you with patterns, for those check `ggpattern::geom_sf_pattern()` , also - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67933907/646761